# Is net_kernel:connect/1 deprecated?

Tags: erlang

I started learning Erlang from Erlang Programming (O'Reilly, 2009) and the `net_kernel:connect/1` function is used in the examples to show how to connect to other nodes.

I tried to look this function up in [the official documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/net_kernel.html) but `net_kernel:connect/1` is not even mentioned and most of the newer sources (eg. Learn You Some Erlang) use `net_kernel:connect_node/1` exclusively.

So far I've come across a couple of commands that were explicitly tagged as deprecated in the doc but there was always an advice on what to use instead. Is `connect/1` kept only for backwards compatibility?

I also [traced back](https://gist.github.com/toraritte/2eddbbddddc4841d403c) both functions and they both are translated to `net_kernel:request({connect, normal, Node})` at one point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `net_kernel:connect/1` function isn't deprecated, but for applications you should use the `net_kernel:connect_node/1` function. In the Erlang/OTP source code, the `net_kernel:connect/1` function is called only by Erlang BIFs related to Distributed Erlang. Though as you've observed both it and `net_kernel:connect_node/1` eventually result in calls to `net_kernel:request/1`, the `net_kernel:connect/1` function first performs checks related to Distributed Erlang.

Comment: I just started up on OTP behaviours and based on what I saw `net_kernel:connect_node/1` is just an alias to `net_kernel:request/1` whereas `net_kernel:connect/1` makes extra checks that seemed superfluous but starting to see the bigger picture it makes perfect sense. Thanks!